# How to get Mathematica to simplify/refine a Polygamma expression of fractions

Tags: algebra

I got the following ugly ev[n] as the least  complicated answer to a Fourier coefficient  integral

```
      Integrate[Cos[t]*Sin [(2 n + 1)*t]/Sin[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}
```

But it refuses to refine /simplify further

```
 ev[n : _] = 
 Refine[FullSimplify[
 1/4 (-1)^
 n (4/(1 + 2 n) - PolyGamma[1/4 - n/2] + PolyGamma[3/4 - n/2] + 
  PolyGamma[1/4 + n/2] - PolyGamma[3/4 + n/2]), {n \[Element] 
 Integers, n > -1}], {n \[Element] Integers, n > -1}]
```

Just gives me the same thing back whereas

```
 FullSimplify[{ev[0], ev[1], ev[2], ev[3], ev[5]}]

{1, 5/3, 23/15, 167/105, 5471/3465}
```

evaluation gives simple fractions.Surely there must be some rational function of n that is a simplication of these PolyGamma's for integers. How do I get Mathematica to simplify to it?

Amazingly  comprehensive beautiful  answers.  To those who have already put so much time into their answers I should have at least explainned  this problem is the wingwise integral of the negative correction  to wing circulation in first order lifting line theory for rectangular wing. Its suprising difficulty shows how hard it is to work  lifting line theory through analytically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

int[n_] = Assuming[{Element[n, Integers], n > -1}, 
  Integrate[Cos[t]*Sin[(2 n + 1)*t]/Sin[t], {t, 0, Pi/2}]]

(* 1/4 (-1)^n (4/(1 + 2 n) - PolyGamma[0, 1/4 - n/2] + PolyGamma[0, 3/4 - n/2] + 
   PolyGamma[0, 1/4 + n/2] - PolyGamma[0, 3/4 + n/2]) *)
```

Generating a sequence

```
seq = {#, int[#]} & /@ Range[0, 10] // FullSimplify

(* {{0, 1}, {1, 5/3}, {2, 23/15}, {3, 167/105}, {4, 491/315}, {5, 5471/3465}, {6,
   70493/45045}, {7, 14191/9009}, {8, 1200229/765765}, {9, 22894441/
  14549535}, {10, 22821511/14549535}} *)
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find a closed-form for the sequence

```
int2[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // Simplify

(* (-2 (-1)^n + π + 2 n π + 
 2 (-1)^n (1 + 2 n) LerchPhi[-1, 1, 3/2 + n])/(2 + 4 n) *)
```

Checking that the functions are equivalent for a wider range of values for `n`

```
And @@ Table[int[n] == int2[n] // FullSimplify, {n, 0, 100}]

(* True *)
```

Consequently, the result is simplified to a single [`LerchPhi`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html) function rather than four [`PolyGamma`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyGamma.html) functions.

The [`DiscreteLimit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteLimit.html) is

```
DiscreteLimit[int2[n], n -> Infinity]

(* π/2 *)

nmax = 25;

DiscretePlot[int[n], {n, 0, nmax},
 PlotRange -> All,
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Line[{{0, Pi/2}, {nmax, Pi/2}}]}]
```

[image]

Zooming in

```
DiscretePlot[int[n], {n, 0, nmax},
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Line[{{0, Pi/2}, {nmax, Pi/2}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the OEIS. The **first** 4 denominators of `ev[n]` look like odd double factorials. Multipliying by that gives the [OEIS sequence A167576](https://oeis.org/A167576). To be more precise the code

```
{1, 5, 23, 167, 1473, 16413, 211479, 3192975}/Range[1, 15, 2]!! // InputForm
```

returns

```
{1, 5/3, 23/15, 167/105, 491/315, 5471/3465, 70493/45045, 14191/9009}
```

which are the first 8 terms of your sequence.

The information in the entry gives a finite summation which Mathematica converts to `LerchPhi[]`. The final result after `FullSimplify[]` is:

```
ev[n] == (-1)^n LerchPhi[-1, 1, n + 3/2] - (-1)^n/(2 n + 1) + Pi/2
```

Here is the first data line from the OEIS

```
1,5,23,167,1473,16413,211479,3192975,54010305,1030249845,21566327895,
```

and here is a summation formula

```
a(n) = (-1)^(n)*(2*n-3)!!*((1)+(4*n-2)*sum((-1)^(k+n)/(2*k+1), k=0..n-1))
```

Note that `(2 n - 1)!!` are the "odd double factorials" [OEIS sequence A001147](https://oeis.org/A001147). Also see `Factorial2[2 n - 1]`.

Comment: Sorry I don't see where (2 n - 1)!! appears or generally the relevance of these similiar OEIS  but not identical to ev[n] sequences.